# How to send an identifier to an Action in Remix?

Tags: remix.run

I think this is a noob question but can someone clarify this for me? I want to know if a hidden input is a good way to send an identifier to an action.
As far as I know, the user can modify a hidden input in the browser.

What if I have a form that deletes a user and I'm using a hidden field to pass the ID of the user to be deleted to the action? Then user tried to modify the value of the hidden field that matches the ID of another user.  I'm not sure but I'm guessing the other user can be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend that for any request, especially mutations, are validated to ensure the user has the proper permissions.

With that said, to ensure that the user doesn’t tamper with sensitive data, you can sign the data on the server and verify it when the request is processed.

**EDIT:** Possible implementation. Basically we sign each `id` returned from the `loader` and use that as a hidden input. Then in the `action`, we verify that the id hasn't been tampered with. They will only be able to delete users that were returned from the loader.

Again, I would also make sure that the `deleteUser` function verifies that the current user has permissions to delete the specified user, even if the signature is correct.

```js
import { json, redirect, type DataFunctionArgs } from '@remix-run/node'
import { useFetcher, useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react'
import { sign, unsign } from 'cookie-signature'

export async function loader({ request }: DataFunctionArgs) {
  const users = await getUsers()

  return json({
    users: users.map(({ id, name }) => ({
      id: sign(String(id), process.env.COOKIE_SECRET!),
      name,
    })),
  })
}

export async function action({ request }: DataFunctionArgs) {
  const formData = await request.formData()
  const signedId = formData.get('id')
  const verifiedId =
    signedId && unsign(String(signedId), process.env.COOKIE_SECRET!)
  if (!verifiedId) return json({ error: 'Invalid ID' }, { status: 400 })

  const id = Number(verifiedId)
  await deleteUser(id)
  throw redirect('/')
}

export default function Component() {
  const { users } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
  const fetcher = useFetcher<typeof action>()

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Delete Users</h2>
      <ul>
        {users.map(({ id, name }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <fetcher.Form method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value={id} />
              <button>Delete {name}</button>
            </fetcher.Form>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {fetcher.data && <p>{fetcher.data.error}</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This uses the `cookie-signature` package which is also used in Remix cookie sessions.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to me, but how can I do that if, for example, I have a page that loads a user list in a table and has an action to delete a specific user?

Do I need to do the signing in the loader after getting the list and process it in the action?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: It's clear to me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the useSubmit() hook to progammatically submit FormData to your action

```
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const templateId = Number(formData.get("templateId"));
  ...
};

const Template = () => {
  const submit = useSubmit();

  const deleteTemplate = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("templateId", template.id.toString());
    submit(formData, { method: "POST" });
  };
```